# How to get the list of installed Browser Apps in an Android Device Programmatically (Package Names)

Tags: android, android-intent, browser

How to get the list of Installed Browser Apps Package Names in an Android Device Programmatically, So that I have to show the list of Browser Apps in my Mobile.

Comment: How do you want to define "browser app", in programming terms?

Comment: May be an app which handles this kind of intent "android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `Intent` that describes the type of activity that you want to match. Pass that to `queryIntentActivities()` on a `PackageManager`. The resulting list of `ResolveInfo` objects contains details of the activities — and their associated apps — that match the `Intent`. If the list is empty, there are no matches.